# How to validate form in codeonename

Tags: codenameone

i have one question how to validate .from file. I'm not able to get in any documents.
I have created,
first go to project --> src --> right click then it show popup --> **GUI Form**

After this two files created. One is simple java and other one is .form file 
but now i'm not able to get how to connect .form to java class. I'm not able to get any example from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You mean a .gui file?

If you have a .form file you might have inadvertently created a Swing/AWT UI instead of a Codename One UI.

Comment: whenever i try to create new gui form from builder it says this is not a visual project, i'm using intelli idea.

Comment: You are using the old GUI builder which requires that you create a GUI builder project to begin with. This is no longer necessary in the new GUI builder see this post: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/using-the-new-gui-builder.html